# Proc C: Stored procedure call is not at all calling

Tags: oracle-pro-c

Below SQL code is not at yet all executing. Not sure why?

```
printf("id value: %s \n" ,Id);
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND CONTINUE; 

    EXEC SQL at DB_NAME EXECUTE
      BEGIN
       PACK.get_data(:Id, :intSQLCode, :intSQLCount, :fund_cursor);
      END;
    END-EXEC;
    printf( " from SP: %d \n", intSQLCode);
    printf(lmsg, "from SP: %d \n", intSQLCount);
    GetRowCnt = intSQLCount;
    if (GetRowCnt == 0)
    {
        GetRowCnt = 9;  
    }

    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)     
    {
        printf("call failed - SQL Code:%d \n",
                   (int)sqlca.sqlcode);
        intReturn = sqlca.sqlcode;
        return (intReturn);

    }
     if (intSQLCode != 0)     
      {
       printf("returned failure code:%d \n",intSQLCode);
       intReturn = intSQLCode;
       return(intReturn);
      }
```

From the above code: First line of code Id value printf line is executing and it's printing the ID value : FIRST

After that none of the code is not executing means, i'm not seeing any errors/any printf statements which are there in error handling.

I wrote the same code in sample program to test, it's executing and everything is fine. But in application same code is not executing and not printing anything.

Comment: Maybe you should first decide which language you use. C, C++ or Ruby? Do you mean Pro*C? This would be "oracle-pro-c", not "proc"

Comment: yes that's correct .. oracle-pro-c

Comment: Reminder:  use `g++` for C++ and `gcc` for C.  You can use `gcc` for C++ by supplying a common C++ extension or a command line option to tell the compiler to use C++.

Comment: Your example text doesn't compile with C or C++.  Please either change the language tags or edit your post so that it compiles as C or C++.

Comment: What happens when you remove WHEN ERROR CONTINUE?